# Security standards to maintain when storing PAN/Aadhar Card information

Tags: pci-dss

I am being asked by the business teams of my company to store the following information relating to users who sign up:
1. Bank account number
2. PAN Card Number (Permanent Account Number). A unique Tax identification number used by tax authorities in India.
3. Aadhar Card number  (A unique id number assigned to every citizen).

I want to know if there are any security standards I would need to follow (PCI-DSS??) if I need to store any or all of this information. I tried to look up standards that need to be maintained if I have to store this information and did not come up with anything.

This is a very India-specific question.

Comment: Nothing here touches on PCI-DSS; the PAN ("Primary Account Number") that PCI-DSS governs is not the same as the PAN ("Permanent Account Number") you're describing.  And neither bank accounts nor Aadhaar fall under PCI.

Comment: @gowenfawr: Thanks. Do you know what the Aadhar and the India-PAN card fall under?